# Negative sign in the Dirac term from the SUSY Kahler potential

Tags: quantum-field-theory, supersymmetry

I want to calculate the Dirac term from the canonical Kahler potential,
\begin{equation}
K = \Phi ^\ast \Phi \tag{1}
\end{equation} 
 but I'm coming across a pesky negative sign in the final result. I am finding (see derivation below),
\begin{equation} 
- i \bar{\psi} \bar{\sigma} ^\mu \partial _\mu \psi \tag{2}
\end{equation} 
This agrees with lecture notes by [Matteo Bertolini](http://people.sissa.it/~bertmat/teaching.htm) (pg. 87) but is off by sign from lecture notes by [Fernando Quevedo](http://arxiv.org/abs/1011.1491) (pg. 50), while they both supposedly use the same conventions.

I would be okay with deciding Quevedo's notes have an error but my result also seems to contradict the regular Dirac Lagrangian, which in four-vector notation is
\begin{equation} 
{\cal L} _D = + i\bar{\Psi} \gamma ^\mu \partial _\mu \Psi \tag{3}
\end{equation} 
Any ideas where this problem is coming from?

Here are my steps:

The chiral and antichiral superfields take the form (I am using the (+---) metric),
\begin{align} 
& \Phi   = \phi  + \sqrt{2} \theta \psi  + \theta ^2 F + i \theta \sigma ^\mu \bar{\theta} \partial _\mu \phi  - \frac{ i }{ \sqrt{2} } \theta ^2 \partial _\mu \psi \sigma ^\mu \bar{\theta} - \frac{1}{4} \theta ^2 \bar{\theta} ^2 \Box \phi  \tag{4}\\ 
& \Phi   ^\ast  = \phi ^\ast    + \sqrt{2} \bar{\psi}   \bar{\theta}   + \bar{\theta} ^2   F ^\ast  - i \theta \sigma  ^\mu \bar{\theta} \partial _\mu \phi ^\ast  + \frac{ i }{ \sqrt{2} } \bar{\theta}  ^2  \theta \sigma ^\mu \partial _\mu \bar{\psi}  - \frac{1}{4}  \theta  ^2  \bar{\theta}^2  \Box \phi ^\ast \tag{5}
\end{align} 
Calculating the Dirac term involves the product of the second term of $ \Phi ^\ast  $ and the fifth term of $ \Phi $ and vice versa. I find:
\begin{align} 
- i \bar{\psi} \bar{\theta} \theta ^2 \partial _mu\psi \sigma ^\mu \bar{\theta} & = - i \partial _\mu \psi ^\alpha \sigma ^\mu _{ \alpha \dot{\alpha} } \bar{\psi} _{\dot{\beta}}  \bar{\theta} ^{\dot{\beta}} \bar{\theta} ^{\dot{\alpha}} \theta ^2 \tag{6}\\ 
& = \frac{ i }{ 2} \partial _\mu \psi ^\alpha \sigma ^\mu _{ \alpha \dot{\alpha} } \bar{\psi} ^{\dot{\alpha}} \bar{\theta} ^2 \theta ^2 \tag{7}\\ 
& = - \frac{ i }{ 2} \bar{\psi} \bar{\sigma} ^\mu \partial _\mu \psi \bar{\theta} ^2 \theta ^2 \tag{8}
\end{align} 
where in the last step I used the spinor identity, $ \psi \sigma ^\mu \bar{\chi} = - \bar{\chi} \bar{\sigma} ^\mu \psi $. Repeating the calculation for the product of the fifth term of $ \Phi ^\ast $ and the second term of $ \Phi $ and summing the two results gives:
\begin{equation} 
- i \bar{\psi} \bar{\sigma} ^\mu \partial _\mu \psi \bar{\theta} ^2 \theta ^2 \tag{9}
\end{equation} 
which after stripping off the $\theta,\bar{\theta}$ is the result I quote above.

Comment: I apologize for asking a question about a silly minus sign but I can't seem to solve it myself.

Comment: Good physicists make a even number of sign errors.

Comment: @Trimok: Indeed, or they pick the most convenient sign :) I often say to myself, "if this were a minus everything would cancel perfectly and look much simpler; I must have made a sign error!"

Answer (score 3):

The final sign $- i \bar{\psi} \bar{\sigma} ^\mu \partial _\mu \psi$ seems correct if we look at [Matteo Bertolini](http://people.sissa.it/~bertmat/susycourse.pdf), formula $5.2$, page $72$, just notice that the order of $\psi$ and $\bar \psi$ is inverted in the formula and apply $\frac{i}{2}\partial_\mu \psi \sigma ^\mu \bar{\psi} = -\frac{i}{2} \bar{\psi} \bar{\sigma} ^\mu \partial_\mu \psi$.

Comment: Thanks for you response. I fixed the typos. 
1) I don't see a reason why the equation you mentioned (now labelled equation 7) is wrong. I use the identity you mentioned above for the product of Grassman variables and then used the Levi Cevita symbol to raise the index of $\psi_{\dot{\beta}}$.

2)I agree with you that this result agrees with Bertolini's notes. However, I don't think it agrees with Quevedo's notes (bottom of pg 50) nor with the typical expression for the Dirac Lagrangian which both quote a '+' sign in the final expression (see Peskin chapter 3.5 eq 3.83 for Dirac Larangian).

Comment: You have to integrate on the $\bar \theta$. I mean, it is not correct to say $ \bar{\theta} ^{\dot{\beta}} \bar \theta ^{\dot{\alpha}} =-\frac{1}{2}\epsilon^{\dot\alpha \dot\beta}$. Look at page $46$ in Quevedo's notes, you have the same expression that in  Bertolini.

Comment: Thanks again. Sorry, I don't think I was clear. The identity I was using was $\bar{\theta}^{\dot{\alpha}}\bar{\theta}^{\dot{\beta}} = -\frac{1}{2}\epsilon ^{\dot{\beta}\dot{\alpha}}\bar{\theta}^2$.

Looking at pg 46 I see the result does agree with Quevedo's on this page. Though he does contradict himself later... If my result is correct, I still don't understand though why this seems to contradict the typical Dirac Lagrangian though which I'm pretty sure has a positive sign,

${\cal L} _D=i \bar{\Psi}    \gamma ^\mu \partial _\mu \Psi = i \psi _L  \gamma ^\mu \partial _\mu\psi _L + ... $

Comment: @JeffDror : You are right, your expression is correct... I delete the part of my answer about this. For the sign, you compare with the Dirac equation which is using gamma matrices, not Pauli matrices. So, it is not a problem, I think.

Comment: Sorry, I had a typo is my last comment again. Though I think the gamma matrix and Pauli matrix Dirac equation have the same sign since The explicit Lagrangian in terms of Pauli matrices is given by (in the Weyl basis) $i \bar{\Psi}    \partial _\mu \gamma ^\mu \Psi = i \bar{\psi} _L \partial _\mu \bar{\sigma}  ^\mu \psi _L + i \bar{\psi} _R \partial _\mu \sigma  ^\mu \psi _R $ (I denote the four-component Dirac equation with $\Psi $ and the two component with $\psi$), which unfortunately again has a positive sign.

Comment: Well, you do not always use Dirac spinors, in supersymmetry (see Bertolini paper). So, if you use  Weyl spinors, or Majorana spinors, it is ok, you don't have to compare.